tcolorbox and logic formats
I asked chatGPT4 to reproduce something like this with the tcolorbox and bussproofs packages:

However, the code it gave me doesn't quite do the trick. I've been trying to change it but no success so far. Here's the code and what it looks like:
\begin{tcolorbox}[colback=gray!10!white, colframe=gray!70!black, title=STLC]

\begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
    \textbf{Syntax}
        \[
            \begin{array}{r l}
            t ::=\\
                 & x \quad \text{variable} \\
                 & \lambda x.t \quad \text{abstraction} \\
                 & t \, t \quad \text{application} \\
            \end{array}
        \]
\end{minipage}

\vspace{0.5cm}

\begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
    \textbf{Values}
    \[
        \begin{array}{r l}
            v ::= & \lambda x.t \quad \text{abstraction value} \\
        \end{array}
    \]
\end{minipage}

\vspace{0.5cm}

\textbf{Evaluation}
\[
\begin{array}{c}
    \infer[\text{E-App1}]{t_1 t_2 \to t_1' t_2}{t_1 \to t_1'}
    \\[10pt]
    \infer[\text{E-App2}]{v_1 t_2 \to v_1 t_2'}{t_2 \to t_2'}
    \\[10pt]
    \infer[\text{E-AppAbs}]{(\lambda x.t_{12}) v_2 \to [x \mapsto v_2]t_{12}}{}
\end{array}
\]

\end{tcolorbox}


Can I get some help with this?
Thanks!

Please provide complete, fully compilable code.

I bet even the complete code gives you an error, doesn't it? If so, please tell us so and provide the exact text of the error message, along with the code to reproduce it. ChatGPT doesn't produce good LaTeX code. Even when it doesn't simply hallucinate packages and, even, compiles, it's awful. You have to at least be prepared to read the package docs to clean up afterwards ;).

You should provide complete MWE, from your code fragment is not clear which package you use and how you imagine that inrefer should be formulated (standard proof package not support showed result).
So below is code which reproduce shoved desired image, but I'm not sure if this result is correct ...
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{proof}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs}
                
\begin{document}
\begin{tcolorbox}[colback=gray!10!white, colframe=gray!70!black, 
                  title=STLC]
\textbf{Syntax}

    \begin{tblr}{colspec = {Q[r, mode=math] Q[l, mode=math] X[r]},
                 rowsep=1pt}
t ::=   &               &   terms:              \\
        & x             &   variable            \\
        & \lambda x.t   &   abstraction         \\
        & t\, t         &   application         \\
    \addlinespace
v ::=   &               &   values              \\     
        & \lambda x.t   &   abstraction value   \\
    \end{tblr}
\bigskip
\textbf{Evaluation}

    \begin{tblr}{colsep=1pt,
                 colspec = {r Q[l, mode=dmath]},
                 rowsep=7pt}
E-App1      &   \dfrac{t_1 t_2 \to t_1' t_2}{t_1 \to t_1'}      \\
E-App2      &   \dfrac{v_1 t_2 \to v_1 t_2'}{t_2 \to t_2'}      \\
E-AppAbs    &   \dfrac{~}{(\lambda x,t_{12})v_2 \to [x \mapsto v_2]t_{12}}
    \end{tblr}
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{document}



I'd recommend using markup designed for typesetting logic. bussproofs is one option. ebproof is, however, more flexible.
The errors I'm assuming you are getting result from attempting to use \infer outside a prooftree environment.
The following uses:

ebproofs for the inference rules,
tabularx and array for the syntax and
mathtools to get the vertically centred double colon for setting the definitions.

\parskip is adjusted within the tcolorbox to provide a bit more spacing.
This solution intentionally sets all of the syntax in a single tabularx so that alignment of both terms and values is ensured. I used tabularx because I could not find an out-of-the-box solution for typesetting logical grammars/syntax or interpretations. That doesn't mean there isn't one.
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
% ateb: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/717799/ addaswyd o gwestiwn pablo: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/717763/
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{ebproof}
\newcolumntype{M}{>{$}l<{$}}
\newcolumntype{R}{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}X}
\begin{document}
\begin{tcolorbox}[colback=gray!10!white,colframe=gray!70!black,title=STLC]
  \parskip=\bigskipamount

  \subsection*{Syntax}
  
  \begin{tabularx}\linewidth{MMR}
    t \dblcolon= && terms:\\
    & x  &{variable} \\
    & \lambda x.t  &{abstraction} \\
    & t \, t  &{application} \\[\medskipamount]
    v \dblcolon= && values: \\
    & \lambda x.t  &{abstraction value} \\
  \end{tabularx}
  
  
  \subsection*{Evaluation}
  
  \begin{prooftree}
    \hypo{t_1 \to t_1'}
    \infer[left label={E-App1}]1{t_1 t_2 \to t_1' t_2}
  \end{prooftree}
  
  \begin{prooftree}
    \hypo{t_2 \to t_2'}
    \infer[left label={E-App2}]1{v_1 t_2 \to v_1 t_2'}
  \end{prooftree}
  
  \begin{prooftree}    
    \hypo{}
    \infer[left label={E-AppAbs}]1{(\lambda x.t_{12}) v_2 \to [x \mapsto v_2]t_{12}}
  \end{prooftree}
  
\end{tcolorbox}

\end{document}

My images currently suck, so here goes nothing:


How do I persuade convert to render a better quality image? Everything I've tried just gets ignored ....

You should, by now, have learned that ChatGPT doesn't know how to solve problems and, indeed, the code that's produced is ridiculous.
Since you refer to bussproofs, here's how you can reproduce the given picture.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{bussproofs}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}

\begin{document}

\begin{tcolorbox}[colback=gray!10!white, colframe=gray!70!black, title=STLC]
\textbf{Syntax}

\medskip

\begin{tabular*}{\linewidth}[t]{
  @{}
  >{$}l<{$}
  >{$}l<{$}
  @{\extracolsep{\fill}}
  r
  @{}
}
t ::= && terms: \\
      & x & variable \\
      & \lambda x.t & abstraction \\
      & t \, t & application \\[2ex]
v ::= && values: \\
      & \lambda x.t & abstr.\@ value \\
\end{tabular*}

\bigskip

\textbf{Evaluation}

\medskip

\LeftLabel{E-App1}
\AxiomC{$t_1 \to t_1'$}
\UnaryInfC{$t_1t_2\to t_1't_2$}
\DisplayProof

\medskip

\LeftLabel{E-App2}
\AxiomC{$t_2 \to t_2'$}
\UnaryInfC{$v_1t_2\to t_1t_2'$}
\DisplayProof

\medskip

\LeftLabel{E-AppAbs}
\AxiomC{\strut}
\UnaryInfC{$(\lambda x.t_{12}) v_2 \to [x \mapsto v_2]t_{12}$}
\DisplayProof

\end{tcolorbox}

\end{document}


